# Is it possible to run javascript if a .php site is in the src attribute of an img tag?

Tags: xss

An image can be displayed through a .php source if the source has a proper header (as per the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/900207/return-a-php-page-as-an-image) question).

If a website allows `something.php` as the image source, and displays the image (as described above), is it possible to include some kind of javascript in `something.php` that will also run when the hosting site retrieves the image? (This seems like it could open things up to a possible XSS)

Comment: I don't see how PHP is relevant. What's the difference between serving a PHP script that returns JavaScript, and a file that is JavaScript?

Comment: @AndrolGenhald I'd say this is a duplicate, yeah.

Comment: @multithr3at3d Because the website wouldn't allow ``something.js``

Comment: I don't think the file extension really matters...

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question, no it is not possible.

Let's say the image is sourced as below for example.

```
<img src="http://somesite.com/something.php">
```

If `something.php` doesn't render as an image, the browser will display an `[X]` or not display the invalid/corrupt image.

If you throw in some javascript inside `something.php` will have no effect at all.